# Why my interface for learnyousomeerlang trade_fsm is failing?

Tags: concurrency, interface, erlang

I'm slowly learning erlang language using [learnyousomeerlang site](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/content) and I'm currently at "Rage Against The Finite-State Machines" chapter, which builds and describes how [trade_fsm.erl](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/static/erlang/trade_fsm.erl) works. As a part of my learning process I've decided to write an interface for this system, where you can control both trading sides by typing console commands. I think I've done a decent job at writing that, however for some reason I cannot understand, whenever I try to start trading, the clients crash. Here's how it goes:

```
5> z3:init("a", "b").
true
6> z3:display_pids().
First player pid: {<0.64.0>}
Second player pid: {<0.65.0>}.
done
7> z3:p1_propose_trade().
{a}: asking user <0.65.0> for a trade

{b}: <0.64.0> asked for a trade negotiation

done
8> z3:display_pids().    
done
9>
```

And here's my code:

```
-module(z3).
-compile(export_all).

-record(state, {player1,
                player2,
                p1items=[],
                p2items=[],
                p1state,
                p2state,
                p1name="Carl",
                p2name="FutureJim"}).


init(FirstName, SecondName) ->
    {ok, Pid1} = trade_fsm:start_link(FirstName),
    {ok, Pid2} = trade_fsm:start_link(SecondName),
    S = #state{p1name=FirstName, p2name=SecondName,
            player1=Pid1, player2=Pid2,
            p1state=idle, p2state=idle},
    register(?MODULE, spawn(?MODULE, loop, [S])).

display_pids() ->
    ?MODULE ! display_pids,
    done.

p1_propose_trade() ->
    ?MODULE ! {wanna_trade, p1},
    done.

p2_accept_trade() ->
    ?MODULE ! {accept_trade, p2},
    done.

loop(S=#state{}) ->
    receive
        display_pids ->
            io:format("First player pid: {~p}~nSecond player pid: {~p}.~n", [S#state.player1, S#state.player2]),
            loop(S);
        {wanna_trade, Player} ->
            case Player of
                p1 ->
                    trade_fsm:trade(S#state.player1, S#state.player2);
                p2 ->
                    trade_fsm:trade(S#state.player2, S#state.player1);
                _ ->
                    io:format("[Debug:] Invalid player.~n")
            end,
            loop(S);
        {accept_trade, Player} ->
            case Player of
                p1 ->
                    trade_fsm:accept_trade(S#state.player1);
                p2 ->
                    trade_fsm:accept_trade(S#state.player2);
                _ ->
                    io:format("[Debug:] Invalid player.~n")
            end,
            loop(S);
        _ ->
            io:format("[Debug:] Received invalid command.~n"),
            loop(S)
    end.
```

Can anyone tell me why this code fails and how it should be implemented?

Comment: What's the error you're getting on the crash? There's no crash in your console output that I can see.

Comment: @matov that's part of the problem, there's no error message, yet the Pids die and cannot be "banged" (Pid ! Msg) anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call `z3:p1_propose_trade().` it sends the message `{wanna_trade, p1}` to registered process z3.

The message is interpreted in the loop function which calls `trade_fsm:trade(S#state.player1, S#state.player2);` converted into `gen_fsm:sync_send_event(S#state.player1, {negotiate, S#state.player2}, 30000).`. This call is a synchronous call which is waiting for a reply from the fsm, and which timeout after 30 seconds if it did not receive any answer.

In the state wait, you have caught the message in the statement:

```
idle({negotiate, OtherPid}, From, S=#state{}) ->
    ask_negotiate(OtherPid, self()),
    notice(S, "asking user ~p for a trade", [OtherPid]),
    Ref = monitor(process, OtherPid),
    {next_state, idle_wait, S#state{other=OtherPid, monitor=Ref, from=From}};
```

No reply value is returned to the caller. You should have used in the last line something like

```
    {reply, Reply, idle_wait, S#state{other=OtherPid, monitor=Ref, from=From}};
```

or an explicit call to gen_fsm:reply/2.

I didn't dig too much in the code, but if you change it to:

```
idle({negotiate, OtherPid}, From, S=#state{}) ->
    Reply = ask_negotiate(OtherPid, self()),
    notice(S, "asking user ~p for a trade", [OtherPid]),
    Ref = monitor(process, OtherPid),
    {reply, Reply, idle_wait, S#state{other=OtherPid, monitor=Ref, from=From}};
```

it doesn't stop and seems to work properly.

Maybe some one knowing perfectly the behavior of the gen_fsm can give an explanation of what is going behind the scene (why is there nothing printout when the timeout ends, why the shell is ready for a new command while it should be waiting for an answer?):

- If you call manually the function `trade(OwnPid, OtherPid)` you will see that it doesn't return until the 30 second timeout is reached, and then you get an error message.
- when it is called by `z3:p1_propose_trade().`, after 30 seconds the error message is not shown but the registered process z3 dies.

**[EDIT]**

I have checked how the code should work, and, in fact, it doesn't seem necessary to modify the fsm code. The reply should come from the process 2, when the second user accept to negotiate. So you can't do the test this way (loop is waiting for an answer, and it cannot send the accept_trade). here is a session that works:

```
{ok,P1} = trade_fsm:start("a1").
{ok,P2} = trade_fsm:start("a2").
T = fun() -> io:format("~p~n",[trade_fsm:trade(P1,P2)]) end.
A = fun() -> io:format("~p~n",[trade_fsm:accept_trade(P2)]) end.
spawn(T). % use another process to avoid the shell to be locked
A().
```

You can change the "wanna_trade" interface to avoid the blocking issue

```
{wanna_trade, Player} ->
    case Player of
        p1 ->
            spawn(fun() -> trade_fsm:trade(S#state.player1, S#state.player2) end);
        p2 ->
            spawn(fun() -> trade_fsm:trade(S#state.player2, S#state.player1) end);
        _ ->
            io:format("[Debug:] Invalid player.~n")
    end,
    loop(S);
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't check this sooner, learning erlang is a hobby of mine and I haven't quite had time lately. But your solution works! So basically when trade_fsm used `gen_fsm:sync_send_event`, I had to wrap that call in a new process, cause otherwise the z3 process would get stuck waiting for an answer it could never receive, thank you.

Comment: For test purpose yes, but generally you will have several processes involved in an application, and the one which is waiting for the answer should not be the one that trig the answer. Your use case is particular because ask for trading and accepting to trade are both issued from the shell. You can also use several shells in the same VM (Ctrl G, s -> to create a new shell, c 1 and c 2 to connect to the first or second shell)